# Finding the seconds difference between two dates in MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to know how much time has elapsed in seconds from a table field `upload_date` and now, when the query is executed.  After reading some functions of MySQL I tried but wasn't so lucky.

Is there a way to return the value in hours if it was less than 24 hours, and in days, if it was 100 days or less?  Otherwise I will have to code that in PHP.

The date is in CURRENT TIME STAMP format, just to clear that up.

I tried this:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), upload_date) FROM is_meeting_files
```

I also tried this, but it gave a difference of 0 seconds:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), upload_date) AS intval FROM is_meeting_files LIMIT 0,5;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subtract the unix timestamp values from one another:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(NOW()) - unix_timestamp(upload_date) from is_meeting_files;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT
    IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, upload_date, NOW()) <= 24,
        CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, upload_date, NOW()), ' hours'),
        IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, upload_date, NOW()) <= 100,
            CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, upload_date, NOW()), ' days'),
            CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, upload_date, NOW()), ' months'),
        )
    ) as diff
FROM is_meeting_files;
```

This will return "n hours" when diff is less than 24 hours, "n days" if diff is less than 100 days and "n months" when diff is more than 100 days.

From my point of view it's a bad idea to do all this operations in SQL because such kind of queries is not possible to cache and as you see it is not so flexible. So, I recommend you to generate this on a PHP side.

Comment: I did this through php, but thanks for your post. I will attempt to do it in my sql query.